# haskell: factorial using high order function

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to recreate a factorial function, eg fac 1 = 1, fac 2 = 2, fac 3 = 6 by using high order functions but I'm not having much luck. My fold function keeps returning the empty list no matter what inputs I'm giving it. Can anyone help me out?

Here's what I have so far:

```
fold f a [] = []
fold f a (x:xs) = fold f (f a x) xs


fac n = fold (*) 1 [1..n]
```

Comment: Have you tried executing it by hand on a few samples?

Comment: Is the recreating of `foldl` necessary for this exercise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fold` returns the empty list because its base case returns the empty list, and the recursive step never does anything with the result of the recursion.  Obviously, at least one of those things needs to change, and in this instance, that should be the base case:

```
fold f a [] = a
```

Alternatively, you could just use `foldl` itself instead of trying to reimplement it.

Answer (score 1):

With a fold over a list you can achieve it:

```
fact n = foldl1 (*) [1..n]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
fac n=product [1..n]
```

Answer (score 0):

You generate all factorial values as list.

```
facts = scanl (*) 1 [1 ..]
```

After that getting one value is just accessing the list.

```
factN n = facts !! n + 1

λ> factN 6
720
```